# parallelize Own Package in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

As recommended in other posts I wrote my own package in R to parallelize functions I wrote with Rcpp. I can load the package and everything works, but when I'm using optimParallel, I get the message:

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object '_EffES_profileLLcpp' not found

Here is what I'm doing:

```
library(optimParallel)
library(EffES) # EffES is my own package

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(EffES))
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(optimParallel))
setDefaultCluster(cl = cl)

w.es <- optimParallel(par=rep(0.001,3), profileLLcpp, y=y.test, x=x.test, lower = rep(0.001,3), method = "L-BFGS-B")$par

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object '_EffES_profileLLcpp' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Log into the worker node, try loading it and see what happens.  Maybe the `.libPaths()` is different.  Maybe you forgot to install `EffES` on one or more nodes.  We can't tell.

Comment: How many cores does your computer have? Which tools do you use for package development?

Comment: My laptop has 4 cores. I used this instrution (section 4) to build my package:
[link](http://web.mit.edu/insong/www/pdf/rpackage_instructions.pdf). I used the functions `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`, `compileAttributes()` and `package_native_routine_registration_skeleton()` from RcppArmadillo, Rcpp and tools. And then I built and installed it in the commander with `Rcmd build` and `Rcmd INSTALL`

Comment: Is your package source code publicly available, for example in a GitHub repo?

Comment: It's not in a GitHub repo, but maybe this helps:[src](https://codebunk.com/b/515249891/)

Comment: The codebunk link does not help much, since it only contains your "business logic". Here all the glue around that file are of interest. For example, I don't think that there is a need to use `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton()` since `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` already does that.

Comment: And by the same token, if a "complicated" or "non-standard" package fails, try a simpler one.  My first test for distributed work always is to report the process ID, or hardware IP address, or ... back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit: The problem is solved in optimParallel version  0.7-4

The version is available on CRAN: https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=optimParallel

---

### For older versions:

As detailed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770415/1315472) `optimParallel()` needs to trick a bit in order to have no restrictions on the argument names that can be passed through the `...` argument. Currently, this implies that the function passed to `optimParallel()` has to be defined in the `.GlobalEnv` in order to find compiled code properly.

Hence, a workaround could be to define the function in the `.GlobalEnv`:

```
library(optimParallel)
library(EffES)                          # EffES is your own package
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(EffES))
setDefaultCluster(cl=cl)

f <- function(par, y, x) {
    profileLLcpp(par=par, x=x, y=y)
}
optimParallel(par=rep(0.001,3), f=f, y=y.test, x=x.test, 
              lower = rep(0.001,3), method = "L-BFGS-B")$par
```

Suggestions to improve the code of optimParallel() are welcome. I opened a corresponding question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52771870/1315472).

Answer (score 0):

You have to spread the object `'_EffES_profileLLcpp'` to each core of your cluster. You can do this using `clusterExport`, in your case:

```
clusterExport(cl,'_EffES_profileLLcpp')
```

Repeat this step with every object needed to be used in parallel (or just check which object shows up in the error log and spreat it using `clusterExport`).

Hope this helps

Comment: One doesn't need multiple lines. `clusterExport` has `varlist` parameter, so you can specify multiple exports in a single line of code

Comment: True, although maybe you don't know which objects you need to spread in the first place (or at least that's what happened to me because I was trying to run some long and complicated code) and the error indicates which objects need to be spread.