# optimParallel can not find Rcpp function

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, rcpp

I am trying to optimize a Rcpp function parallely using the R package "optimParallel". But I am getting the error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'Likelihood' not found
```

Now, the function "Likelihood" is written in C++ and exported to R via "Rcpp". I found in this link:   [parallelize Own Package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502855/parallelize-own-package-in-r)

that I have to define the function in R global environment, which I did. But it did not solve the problem. I did not write the C++ code here as it is too complex.

Comment: It's a FAQ.  Just scroll back a few questions under the Rcpp tag as we had it recently.  You are too optimistic in thinking that your in-session compiled function magically travels to all other processes.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I saw your link which you think can answer my question. I want to know how to define my code as an object; while the code calls another code (which is basically an integration in C++, so has a functor defined prior defining the integration function) .

Comment: As we say in those previous answers: write a package around that function, have the package loaded by each worker.  There is no other good way.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel; making package following the steps in this link: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio ?